# Splitting a string in spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD[Long,String]. A sample RDD is as follows -

```
(123, name:abc,sr.no:1,name:def,sr.no:2)
```

I want to transform this rdd to have a list of sr.no. Output should look like this-

```
(123, [1,2])
```

I tried this in scala with the flatmap approach, but I want only 1 record for "123" and all the values within an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll maintain the number of records if you use `mapValues`.  Here is a naive function that does what you want:

```
scala> def foo(s: String, pattern: String): Array[String] = s.split(",").filter(_.contains(pattern)).map(_.split(":").last)
foo: (s: String)Array[String]

scala> foo("name:abc,sr.no:1,name:def,sr.no:2", "sr.no")
res3: Array[String] = Array(1, 2)
```

Now you can call:

```
rdd.mapValues(foo(_, "sr.no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to extract the digits after `sr.no:` with *look-behind* syntax `(?<=)`:

```
val p = "(?<=sr.no:)\\d+".r
# p: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<=sr.no:)\d+

rdd.map{case (x, y) => (x, p.findAllIn(y).toList)}.collect()
# res10: Array[(Int, List[String])] = Array((123,List(1, 2)))
```

Or as @Tim commented, use `mapValues()`:

```
rdd.mapValues(p.findAllIn(_).toList).collect()
# res11: Array[(Int, List[String])] = Array((123,List(1, 2)))
```

Comment: You call `map` instead of `mapValues` here unnecessarily, the latter is better practice.